# Making bar charts for big values

Tags: bar-chart

I'm trying to make a bar chart for some kb values, but I'm receiving this error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.254 \bcbar[text=Bule]{19419}
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{bchart}
%opening
\begin{document}
    \begin{bchart}[step=20000,max=100]
    \bcbar[text=Bule]{19419}
    \bcbar[text=Inserție]{19513}
    \bcbar[text=Shell]{19513}
    \bcbar[text=Interclasare]{19517}
    \bcbar[text=Rapidă]{19525}
    \bcbar[text=Selecție]{19537}
    \end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

How can I make a bar chart for these values?
Thanks

Comment: can you please provide code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is well documented in the package `bchart`. What is suggested is to rescale the bars by a factor 10 or so, and use the `value` key to printout the correct values, ie:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{article}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{bchart}[step=100,max=200]
\bcbar[text=Bule,value=19419]{194.19}
\bcbar[text=Inserție,value=19513]{195.13}
\bcbar[text=Shell,value=19513]{195.13}
\bcbar[text=Interclasare,value=19517]{195.17}
\bcbar[text=Rapidă,value=19525]{195.25}
\bcbar[text=Selecție,value=19537]{195.37}
\end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]